# Why there is "Loading..." below all my posts?

Tags: wordpress

I don't know recently what I've config but now, at the bottom of every posts, there is always this word

```
"Loading..."
```

I spend a lot of time to find out but there is no clue.

Have you ever met this case before?
Please share your solution.

Comment: It's better to paste your website url

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved it.

It because I choose *"Show Sharing Buttons"* on each post but the button cannot be loaded.